# Why does Enumerable.Range Implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, iterator, idisposable, resource-management

Just wondering why `Enumerable.Range` implements `IDisposable`.

I understand why `IEnumerator<T>` does, but `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't require it.

---

(I discovered this while playing with my .Memoise() implementation, which has statement like

```
if (enumerable is IDisposable)
    ((IDisposable)enumerable).Dispose();
```

in its "source finished" method that I had placed a breakpoint on out of curiousity, and was triggered by a test.)

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range` uses `yield return` in its method body. The `yield return` statement produces an anonymous type that implements `IDisposable`, under the magic of the compiler, like this:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

After being compiled, there is an anonymous nested class like this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <GetNumbers>d__0 
   : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<int>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
{
    //the implementation
    //note the interface is implemented explicitly
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }
}
```

so the result `is` a `IDisposable`. In this example, the `Dispose` method leaves empty. I think the reason is that there is nothing need to be disposed. If you `yield return` a type that contains unmanaged resources, you may get a different compiling result. (NOT SURE about it)

Comment: The compiler implements both IEnumerable and IEnumerator with the same class? Interesting. I'll have to think about that works.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. It uses its state machine to detect if GetEnumerator has been called multiple times and returns itself if it hasn't.

Comment: That makes sense, but having a factory method return a type which implements `IDisposable` when the return type of the factory does not would seem to be an anti-pattern.  Compiler-generated iterators produced via `yield return` would appear to be types where abandonment without disposal would in fact be harmless provided `GetEnumerator()` has never been called, but once `GetEnumerator()` has been called, disposal is generally necessary.  Incidentally, calling `Dispose` on an iterator after `GetEnumerable()` has been called at least once will invalidate the first enumerator only.

Comment: Is calling `Dispose` on a iterator defined to invalidate (or not) all of its enumerators though? Either way having different behaviour for the first `GetEnumerable` call is unexpected. Premature optimisation by the compiler?

Comment: (To clarify @supercat, calling `Dispose` on a compiler generated `IEnumerable` implementation is *never* necessary, unless you're mishandling the iterator.)

Comment: @Fowl: If an iterator performs a return within the `try` portion of a `try`/`finally` block, the `finally` portion will only execute when the iterator is disposed.

Comment: @supercat We're not disagreeing?